# Pass Variable from iOS to watchOS

Tags: ios, swift, variables, watchkit, avaudioplayer

In my viewController, I have a varible for an AVAudioPlayer

```
var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
```

I want to acess this varible in my watchKit app so that I can play and pause the AVAudioPlayer from the watchKit app. Like

```
audioPlayer.play()
audioPlayer.pause()
```

How can I acess this variable from my watchKit app? Thanks for the help! I'm using Swift 3 and Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

Since watchOS 2, you can't use AppGroups to share data directly between your iOS app and the WatchKit app.

Your only option to communicate between the two is the [WatchConnectivity](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity) framework. Using WatchConnectivity, you can signal the iOS app using instant messaging to start/stop playing. On iOS in your AppDelegate implement something like this:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        if let content = message["play"] as? [String:Any] {
            audioPlayer.play()
            replyHandler(["startedPlaying":true])
        } else if let content = message["pause"] as? [String:Any] {
            audioPlayer.pause()
            replyHandler(["pausedMusic":true]) 
        }
}
```

And in your Watch app you need to send messages with the content specified in your AppDelegate's `session(_:didReceiveMessage:replyHandler:)`. If you don't need to send a response back to the Watch app, you can just use `session(_:didReceiveMessage:)` and get rid of the `replyHandler` part.